# open and close an inappbrowser in an ionic app

Tags: javascript, cordova, browser, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I am building an ionic app and using the cordova inappbrowser plugin. From within my  App  I need to open an external web page using the inappbrowser.  On this web page I need to provide a custom close button to the user, which closes the browser window when clicked.

I have looked at a number of existing threads such as 
[Phonegap build - Open external page in InAppBrowser or childbrowser with no toolbar and close it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666258/phonegap-build-open-external-page-in-inappbrowser-or-childbrowser-with-no-tool)

[window.close equivalent in Phonegap with InAppBrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191793/window-close-equivalent-in-phonegap-with-inappbrowser/15981972#15981972)

[How can I get the cordova InAppBrowser to provide a way for the user to close the browser when using an Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15348871/how-can-i-get-the-cordova-inappbrowser-to-provide-a-way-for-the-user-to-close-th/31793577#31793577)

While I am able to get inappbrowser window to open my url using

```
window.open('http://myurl.com', '_blank', 'location=no').
```

I am not able to close the inappbrowser window using the approaches suggested.

When I use

```
var ref = window.open(encodeURI(url), '_blank', options);
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) {        
if (event.url.match("mobile/close")) {
    ref.close();
}
});
```

However the link on the webpage 
    `<a href="/mobile/close">Close</a>`

does not close the inappbrowser window. On clicking it shows a 404 not found error.

I have also tried [impossible to close inAppBrowser window [Solved]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199691/impossible-to-close-inappbrowser-window-solved)
But no success. 
Please help. Thanks

Comment: check out this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38592848/how-to-quit-the-application-from-my-android-device-back-button-in-cordova/38604023#38604023 this closes inapp browser on click of back button. Hope it helps.keep me posted

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately my requirement is such that I need to create a button to close the browser and cannot depend on the back button.

Comment: Then you gotta checkout themeable browser - https://github.com/initialxy/cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser